# 550 error on retrieving filesize while uploading file

Tags: powershell, ftp, webclient

I'm trying to get the file size while I'm uploading the file. My end goal is to try and get the upload speed, but in my while loop i get a Exception calling "OpenRead" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

Please see code below

```
$uploadRemoteFile = "Remote URI"
$ftpuname = "UserName"
$ftppassword = 'Password'

function upload-ftp{
    $File = "$env:TEMP\something.exe"
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($ftpuname,$ftppassword); 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($uploadRemoteFile)
    $webclient.UploadFileAsync($Uri, $File)
    $arrayftp = @()
    Function Get-newfilesize{
        $webclientRead = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
        $webclientRead.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($ftpuname,$ftppassword); 
        [void]$webclientRead.OpenRead($uri);
        [Int64]$bytes_total= ($webclientRead.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"])
        $webclientsize = ($bytes_total.ToString());
        $webclientsize
    }
    while ($webclient.IsBusy){
        $oldftpfile = Get-newfilesize;

        $oldftpdate = Get-Date;

        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1

        $newftpfile = Get-newfilesize;
        $newftpdate = Get-Date;

        $ftpsizediff = $newftpfile - $oldftpfile;
        $ftptimediff = $newftpdate - $oldftpdate;

        $totalftpdiff = $ftpsizediff / $ftptimediff.totalseconds;
        $totalftpdiff  | foreach {
            if ($_ -gt 0){$arrayftp += $_ }
        }
    }
    $testftpcap= New-Object psobject -Property @{"Upload Speed" =((($arrayftp | measure -Average).Average/1MB)* 10)}
    $testftpcap | Export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $env:TEMP\ftpspeed.csv
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a direct answer to your question but you could use Powershell FTP module - works great and has a progress bar too..
(http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb)